# Accessing parent table laravel model with relation where parent column comparison

Tags: laravel, eloquent, laravel-relations

I have been having this problem for few days, and there were no documentation on Laravel web or any issue related on google search. So I was wondering if it is possible or if I could do it any other way except loading all data from database to a variable and do the filtering.

**Fetching relations with an addition to another parent table(cooperatives.next_due_date) CODE**

```
$coperatives = Cooperative::withNextDueDate()
        ->has("shares")
        ->with(["shares.lastDue" => function ($q) {
             $q->whereRaw("due_in <> cooperatives.next_due_date");        
        }])
        ->get();
```

**Returned Error**

Unknown column 'cooperatives.next_due_date' in 'where clause'

**Problem**

I want to get cooperatives with shares that has due dates that are not of cooperative's next_due_date.

*cooperatives table columns looks like this:*
{
id,name,next_due_date
}-> hasMany(Share)

*shares table columns looks like this:*
{
id,cooperative_id
} -> hasMany(ShareDue)

*share_dues table columns looks like this:*
{
id,cooperative_share_id
}->belongsTo(Share)

That lastDue is the shareDue from all shares, it's just hasOne(ShareDue) with latest instead of hasMany(ShareDue)

Comment: Did you ever solve this? I'm struggling with the same issue.

Comment: Nop I did not find any answer till now